# Linking to or importing from Microsoft Graph in Access for Office 365

Tags: microsoft-access

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/link-to-or-import-data-from-microsoft-graph-448d8bf1-0f54-46c4-91bc-490d5ebfdadd allegedly tells how to import or link to Microsoft Graph from Microsoft Access for Office 365. The connector was announced for version 1904 of Access at https://insider.office.com/en-us/releasenotes/pc/slow?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fwhat-s-new-for-office-insiders-c152d1e2-96ff-4ce9-8c14-e74e13847a24 (search on "1904" to see details). However, I am on version 1907 and don't have the required option when I click on External Data --> Import & Link--> New Data Source --> From Online Services. All I see there are SharePoint List, From Dynamics 365 (online), From Salesforce and Data Services.

I am using Access for Office 365 32-bit version 1907 on automatic update on Window 10 Pro 64-bit.

There are no error messages, just no option available.

Answer (score 0):

A kind gentleman at Microsoft found out for me that its launch is now only planned for Q1 2020. See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=In%20development&searchterms=Microsoft%2CGraph. Thus it looks like they launched it in version 1904 of Access (on the Insider track, i.e. not for general availability), had to pull it and are only expecting to launch it fully early next year. That's disappointing, but hey ho.